# How to correctly set Allow header for a HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED status code in Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I'm currently looking to disable certain methods for an API endpoint - as added security. I'm using the status code that DRF suggests to use, that is for my case, "`HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED`" - however, it looks to me that although this is working, the headers still say that the method is in Allow. See screenshot below:

[image: HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED Django Rest Framework example]

As you can see, I am performing a GET request - but the Allow header is saying it's fine - even tho the status code is being applied correctly.

Stripped back example code:

```
class TokenValidateView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, headers=?)
```

I believe I would need to set something in the headers dictionary (I've added `?` where I'm not quite sure what needs to be done) as one of the arguments in the Response() function, but I'm not sure if this is a bug in DRF itself? Surely when that status code is passed it should be set in the headers accordingly?

N.B. I've also tried adding `headers = { 'Allow': 'POST' }` to the `Response()` argument, but that doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the **`APIView`** class, it will allow all the methods which are defined in your view class. The DRF response allowed the **`HTTP GET`** method because you'd defined in on your view.

---

The below view class will allow **`HTTP GET,HTTP POST,HTTP PATCH,HTTP PUT and HTTP DELETE`**

```
class TokenValidateView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # something
        return Response("this is HTTP GET")

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("this is HTTP POST")

    def patch(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("this is HTTP PATCH")

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("this is HTTP PUT")

    def delete(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("this is HTTP DELETE")
```

As I said above, the response class checks the ***http methods*** inside the view class, ***not their responses***.
So, If you want to remove the **`HTTP GET`** method from your ***Allowed Methods***, just remove the **`get()`** method from the view class

```
class TokenValidateView(APIView):
    # remove the "get()" method
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # something
        return Response("this is HTTP GET")

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("this is HTTP POST")

    def patch(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("this is HTTP PATCH")

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("this is HTTP PUT")

    def delete(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("this is HTTP DELETE")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you override the `get` method of the view,`GET` is automatically added to the `Allow` header by django-rest-framework, no matter what Response you return. You can simply remove `get` method if you want it to return `405 Not Allowed`.

If for a reason, you want to keep `get` method and do not include `GET` in to the `Allow` header, you can override `allowed_methods` property in your view:

```
@property
def allowed_methods(self):
    allowed_methods = super().allowed_methods
    allowed_methods.remove('GET')
    return allowed_methods
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the method just don't implement it on view which is subclassing ApiView. It will automatically send the method not allowed response.